# Create Button from each item in array React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with Unsplash API and I am trying to get the images to download. I can get them to download, however it downloads every single photo instead of just the one I want when I use a for loop. If I remove the saveAs part outside of the loop it only downloads the final image in the array instead of the others no matter what button I click. Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Heading } from './components/Heading';
import { Loader } from './components/Loader';
import { UnsplashImage } from './components/UnsplashImage';
import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroll-component';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';


import axios from 'axios';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';
import SearchPhotos from './components/searchPhotos';
import Heart from './components/Heart';
import { FileUpload } from './components/Upload';

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  *{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body{
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }
`;

const WrapperImg = styled.section`
  max-width: 70rem;
  margin: 4rem auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
`;

const H1 = styled.h1`
  max-width: 70rem;
  margin: 4rem auto;
`;

const Div = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
`;


function App() {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchImages();
  }, [])

  const fetchImages = () => {
    const apiURL = "https://api.unsplash.com";
    const apiKey = "MY_KEY_";
    axios
      .get(`${apiURL}/photos/random?client_id=${apiKey}&count=1`)
      .then(res => setImages([...images, ...res.data]))
  }

  const imgURL = images.map((download) => {
    //console.log(download.urls.full)
    return download.urls.full;
  });

  const Download = () => {
    const downloadImage = () => {
      for (var i = 0; i < imgURL.length; i++) {
        var red = imgURL[i];
        //saveAs(red, 'image.jpg');
        console.log(red);
      } 
      //saveAs(red, 'image.jpg');

    }
    return <button onClick={downloadImage}>Download</button>
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Heading />
      <GlobalStyle />
      <SearchPhotos />
      <InfiniteScroll
        dataLength={images.length}
        next={fetchImages}
        hasMore={true}
        loader={<Loader />}
      >
        <H1>Main Feed:</H1>
        <WrapperImg>
          <FileUpload />
          {images.map(image =>
          (<>
            <Div>
              <Heart />
              <UnsplashImage url={image.urls.thumb} key={image.id} />
              <p className="like"> Amount of Likes ❤️ {image.likes}</p>
              <Download />
            </Div>
          </>))}
        </WrapperImg>
      </InfiniteScroll>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Why are you passing the complete array in saveAs method?

Comment: Sometimes I find it useful to split the code to a different files that way you can make sure what it the right context (it looks like you are creating only one button)

Comment: I am not the best with JS or React for that matter, i'd say i am pretty new to all this, where would I add the for loop if not there?

Comment: Can you post your entire JSX contents.  From where are you getting `images` ? Where is `Download`  included?

Comment: Yeah let me edit it to show my whole App.js
There now you can see where i am using Download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to download each image, I have removed loop and modified the `Download` function

```
  const imgURL = images.map((download) => {
    //console.log(download.urls.full)
    return download.urls.full;
  });

    const downloadImage = (index) => {
       var red = imgURL[index];
        saveAs(red, 'image.jpg');    
    }


  return (
    <div className="App">
        <WrapperImg>
          {images.map((image,index) =>
          (<>
            <Div>
              <UnsplashImage url={image.urls.thumb} key={image.id} />
              <button onClick={()=> { downloadImage(index) }>Download</button>
            </Div>
          </>))}
        </WrapperImg>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
// the download buttons with specific links will all be stored in the array returned here
const allYourDownloadButtons = images.map((download) => {
    let imgURL = download.urls.full;
    // saveAs was not mentioned in your code, if it's in scope here, you can directly pass it
    return <DownloadV2 imgURL={imgURL} saveAs={saveAs} />;
});

const DownloadV2 = ({ imgURL, saveAs }) => {
    return <button onClick={() => saveAs(imgURL, 'image.jpg')}>Download</button>;
};
```

Once you display the buttons on the UI, clicking on them will pass the specific URL through `saveAs`.

In case you need to know how to use this, please share in the question where you were calling this button.

A very generic way to use it would be like this:

```
<div className="allMyDownloadButtons">
    {allYourDownloadButtons}
</div>
```

Edit: based on your updates I can see that your job is even easier as you were already looping through the images:

```
<WrapperImg>
    <FileUpload />
    {images.map((image) => (
        <>
            <Div>
                <Heart />
                <UnsplashImage url={image.urls.thumb} key={image.id} />
                <p className="like"> Amount of Likes ❤️ {image.likes}</p>
                <DownloadV2 imgURL={image.urls.full} />
            </Div>
        </>
    ))}
</WrapperImg>
```

Comment: I just updated my question, you can see the whole App.js page now if that would help you better understand what i am doing

Comment: I just tried this as well, also works exactly how it should for me! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

### You have this question - firstly understand this What is the happening

---

You can open it in codepen vanilla Javascript or you can skip this. - [enter link description here](https://codepen.io/hr-meheraj/pen/yLvNeBe)

```
const root = document.querySelector("#root");

const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
arr.map(each => {
  const newButton = document.createElement("button");
  newButton.innerHTML = each;
  newButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log(each);
  })
  root.appendChild(newButton);
})
```

### Now Come to your code :

```
 <WrapperImg>
      <FileUpload />
      {images.map(image =>
      (<>
        <Div>
          <Heart />
          <UnsplashImage url={image.urls.thumb} key={image.id} />
          <p className="like"> Amount of Likes ❤️ {image.likes}</p>
          <Download downloadUrl={image.urls.full} />
        </Div>
      </>))}
    </WrapperImg>
```

### Now you can go to the Download Component and edit it.

```
const Download = ({downloadUrl}) => {
const downloadImage = () => {
   saveAs(downloadUrl, 'image.jpg');
 } 

}
return <button onClick={downloadImage}>Download</button>
```

}

### Here you don't need these code below

```
const imgURL = images.map((download) => {
//console.log(download.urls.full)
  return download.urls.full;
 });
```